# How do you dance the pirate polka?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Gendarran Fields, there is a skill challenge issued by Klakka the Brain where you can either fight her or dance the "pirate polka" in order to get the skill point.

How do you do the dance?

Comment: Are you sure it's possible? I thought the intent was, since you don't know the pirate polka, you must fight.

Comment: @RavenDreamer No, I'm not sure it's possible. I figured the ability may be a reference to another part of the game where you can learn such a thing, or that a command like /dance would net you the skill point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't such a thing.

Skill points are divided into three categories.

Combat - Beat the NPC to gain a skill point.

Item - Clicking on the skill challenge will give you an item that will grant you a skill point when used, sometimes with a comical transformation to go with it.

Channeling - Click on the skill challenge and stand there without interruptions for a couple of seconds to gain a skill point. These types of skill challenges usually look like floating spheres of energy.

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, that is another, much rarer type of skill challenge which involves answering questions from the NPC. [This](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Oola)  is one example.

Comment: Indeed, adding something so specific just as an alternative to a fight seems unreasonable.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann it actually would have been funny to make the /dance  command actually useful for one specific challenge in order to justify its existence! :)

Comment: Yes, it would. Or a mini-event like the whole Mad King (a. k. a. Simon, I guess) Says we had on halloween. But a separate quest line (as much as the term is applicable to GW2) is a bit overkill, isn't it?

Comment: There's an additional type, which doesn't occur as often as the others, which is the pop quiz! Some skill points require you to remember information the NPC gives you and answer questions about it correctly.

Comment: @FAE I can't recall if I ever ran across that type. The wiki also doesn't mention those types. Do you remember any locations with that sort of skill challenges?

Comment: Found [one](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Oola) where you have to listen to an asura hologram, then answer questions to prove that you aren't an idiot.

...I failed on my first try. And then again when I posted this as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann Thanks! I'm gonna edit that into my answer.

Comment: There's actually one skill challenge where you need to shoot cannon balls at targets.

Answer (score 4):

The 'Pirate Polka' is pirate speak for walking the plank. So what she's ACTUALLY saying is; either fight or leave, there is no dancing involved sadly.

Comment: Tried `/dance` and it didn't work. Now I feel dumb...

Answer (score 0):

Any dance will work for the pirate polka, I think. I haven't fully tested it yet, but I left my charr dancing in front of Klakka, and when I spoke to her next, she thanked me for cheering up her crew. You have to dance for a while, though; perhaps one full cycle of the animation.